# How to cancel form inheritance

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have several forms that inherit from another form called "BaseForm".

Now, I would like to cancel this relationship.

How can I do that?

I tried deleting the only declaration I saw in my form which is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Shuki.BaseForm
{
/////
}
```

after I deleted it, it looked like this:

```
public partial class Form1 
{
/////
}
```

But when I compile the code the build fails and the error shown is:

> Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Your form must be inherited with at least `System.Windows.Form`

Comment: For a class to be a Windows form, it must inherit Windows.Form class, that provides it the visuals and all the features of the form. You are getting the error because, there is no Dispose method in your Form1 class.
In case, you need to implement your own Dispose method that should be automatically called by the environment, implement IDisposable interface in your class and write your resource releasing code in Dispose method.

Comment: Find out what `Shuki.BaseForm` inherits from and change `Form1` to inherit from that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already stated in the comments, instead of simply removing the base class, change it to `Form`.  All WinForm classes must inherit from `Form`.

In other words, change this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Shuki.BaseForm
{
/////
}
```

To this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
/////
}
```

The reason it complains about `Dispose` is because somewhere in your code (most likely in the other partial class in the `Designer` file, it declares a `Dispose` method as `override`.  Overriding a method is, of course, invalid unless you have a base class that declares the method in the first place.  When you removed the base class, that made the override of the `Dispose` method no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

```
public sealed class {
}
```